# How to stream a mp4 video from windows laptop to raspberry using direct network cable

Tags: ethernet, streaming-video, laptop

I'm working on a video processing research using Raspberrypi3. Since the program getting slow when mp4 video process on a raspberry pi, I want to stream the video from windows laptop to the raspberry Pi via ethernet cable to. The streaming video frames are processed one by one using python and OpenCV programming. Most of the tutorials found from streaming videos from raspberry Pi. I have been struggling with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A program written using python and opencv is processing image frames of a mp4 video. This program runs perfectly on a ubuntu machine. But it getting slow and stuck on a raspberrypi. Therefor i want to stream the video from a different machine(windows) to the raspberrypi.

Comment: Processing is done on the rpi. I want to stream MP4 on windows laptop to the rpi via ethernet cable.

Comment: Yes, That's why I wanted to stream the MP4 video from a different computer(windows laptop)

Comment: but you still want to do the processing on the pi ... I seriously don't get wht you want - deleting my comments as I'm more confused now than before I asked you anything